# Wallpaper application size too big?

Tags: android, wallpaper

I'm creating a High Quality wallpaper app for samsung galaxy s4 resolution(1080x1920) Picture size is 1.5-3.5 MB each. I'm wondering, How come most of wallpaper apps is smaller than 1 MB if mine is 100++. If they save pictures on sd card then it doesn't count in play store? Or do they save on internet and load the pictures from it?

Answer (score 0):

probably because the app downloads the wallpaper files from a server after it's installed...